# Error: Selecting radio button from list with JQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a code where i am selecting radio button using the .prop() method. Issue is sometime the 2nd one (Payment method) is not selected and the script crash and show error because of that here is the code i am using to select radio button.

```
/**
 * Select shipping method when selected from the list
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $options = $('.shipping-method .item');

    $options.click(function(e) {
        var $current = $(this);
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        $options.removeClass('on')
        $current.addClass('on')
        $('input', $current).prop('checked', true)
    })
})
/**
 * Select payment method when selected from the list
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $options = $('.payment-method .item');

    $options.click(function(e) {
        var $current = $(this);
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        $options.removeClass('on')
        $current.addClass('on')
        $('input', $current).prop('checked', true)
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="item"><a href="javascript:;" class="shipping_3">Home Delivery</a>
        <input name="shipping" type="radio" class="radio" id="shipping_3" value="3" checked="checked" supportcod="1" insure="0" onclick="selectShipping(this)">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="item"><a href="javascript:;" class="shipping_8">Self-pickup</a>
        <input name="shipping" type="radio" class="radio" id="shipping_8" value="8" supportcod="1" insure="0" onclick="selectShipping(this)">
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you put HTML code?

Comment: can you also add the error log when it crashes?

Comment: Why two times same code? use one time like this:- `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.payment-method .item, .shipping-method .item').click(function(e) {
        var $current = $(this);
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        $options.removeClass('on')
        $current.addClass('on')
        $('input', $current).prop('checked', true)
    })
})`

Comment: Error: Notice: Undefined variable: payment in public_html/checkout.php on line 2167

Comment: In your given code you have `onclick="selectShipping(this)"` on radio buttons so your jQuery code will not work there

Comment: How can i make it work is there any workaround

Comment: According to your error, the problem must be in another part of the Javascript code, because there is no mention of any variable `payment` in the code shown in the question.